# iPhone view within a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi I want to create an application with a similar home screen to Photovine.

It seems to have the parent view, but within the parent view it has a sort of subview which you can scroll through, Just wondering how this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the Photovine, but what you are searching for might be [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922). You can always add a subview to another view. If you want subview to be scrollable, you can use UIScrollView or one of its implementation (UITableView etc.)

Programatically you would do this as follows:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);

[mainView addSubview:scrollView];
```

Here I created UIScrollView of size 300x300 with content of size 1000x1000. You **must** define content size. If you want UIScrollView to be scrollable, content size must exceed UIScrollView's.

**EDIT:**
To lock scrolling to page, you can use

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: it scrolled horizontally with the pages like the springboard. How would I go about doing that.

Comment: Just restrict scrolling to horizontal only.

Comment: You can't restrict scrolling to horizontal, however if you make sure that height of the content equals height of the scrollView, but the width is larger, the content will scroll only horizontally.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to imitate page scrolling (scrolling page-by-page), you can use `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;` . Try it, it is quite simple.

Comment: pagingEnabled = YES does not seem to work. its like a normal scroll bar.

Comment: it is normal scroll, however scrolling is "locked" to the scrollView dimensions. In other words, user can't scroll only half of the scroll "screen", he can only scroll full screen. Is that what you are searching for or do you need something else? I  can't download Photovin, it's not in Slovene app store to check it out.